# using push_back to put a vector<double> into a vector<vector<double>>

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a `std::vector<vector<double>>` I want to fill in one function.
I need to store some 3 dimensional coordinates for some calculations later in my program.

My Question is if I do this:

```
//in classdefinition
std::vector<std::vector<double>> data;

    myFunc()
    {
        std::vector<double> temp;
        temp.push_back(1);
        temp.push_back(2);
        temp.push_back(3);
        data.push_back(temp);

        temp.clear();
        //new data
        temp.push_back(2);
        temp.push_back(3);
        temp.push_back(4);
        data.push_back(temp);
    }
```

will the clearing and refilling of temp influence the values in data?

I already found this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/
but since the explanation reads "The content of val is copied (or moved) to the new element." I don't know what to think. To me this sounds like a contradiction.

I think it would not make much sense if the variables are passed as a reference since they can, like in my case, only be valid in a limited scope.
Am I right with my assumption?

Answer (score 5):

If `data` is of type `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` then you're fine: a *value copy* of `temp` will be taken; so you're free to do as you please with `temp` after you've used it as the `push_back` argument.

If, however, you've messed about with the vector's *allocator* then you might need to take more care.

Using *emplacement* (see `emplace_back`) can obviate the unnecessary deep copy:

```
// First row of data
{
    std::vector<double> temp = {1, 2, 3}; /*ain't C++11 brilliant?*/
    data.emplace_back(std::move(temp)); /*do not use temp after this line - 
                                use scope blocks so you're not tempted*/
}
```

You *could* do that as a one-liner although in reality I suspect you want to populate `temp` with a bit more care. So I've kept the two lines separate.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in doc there are two overloaded versions of `push_back` function

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
void push_back (value_type&& val);
```

The first takes const reference to `val` and copies it into vector. The second one uses rvalue reference (see [move sematics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/2807083) for more information) and *moves* `val` into vector leaving source vector empty.
Neither of them stores reference to temporary object inside vector.

First version will call when you pass, for example, local variable.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> v;
std::vector<double> lv = {1, 3, 7};
v.push_back(lv);
```

the second one - when you pass temporary variable or explicitly move variable

```
v.push_back(std::vector<double>({0, 17, 42}));
v.push_back(std::move(lv));
```

Comment: Oh sorry i did not see i had C++98 selected instead of C++11, therefor i did not see the overloaded function and was confused.

Answer (score 1):

"copied" refers to push_back(temp) and "(or moved)" refers to push_back(std::move(temp))